# Replacing multiple values in CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file where one of the columns is titled "Type". Under this column I'm trying to replace values "Ford" and "GMC" as "Automotive". I believe with what I have, there's definitely an issue with formatting. Please advise.

```
df_jobs["Type"].replace(to_replace = "Ford", "GMC", value = "Automotive", inplace=True)
```

The error I'm getting is

```
"SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument"
```

Answer (score 2):

Error is self explanatory. `"GMC"` is a positional argument which is followed by `to_replace = "Ford"` which is a keyword argument.
What you need is make a list of `"Ford"` and `"GMC"` and then pass it to `to_replace` key:

```
df_jobs["Type"].replace(to_replace = ["Ford", "GMC"], value = "Automotive", inplace=True)
```